# Let$\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be bounded. Then $\sum_0^{\infty} z^na_n$ converges for $|z|<1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

How to prove:

> Let $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be bounded. Prove $\sum_0^{\infty} z^na_n$ converges for $|z|<1$

So far I prove that the partial sums form a Cauchy sequence, i.e. $\{S_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy.

How do I proceed?

---

I think I should suppose the limit is $0$ at first, and then prove that there exists an integer $K$ such that for every $\epsilon$, when $k>K$, $|S_k-0|<\epsilon$.

But where could I use the fact that I have proved (i.e. partial sums form a Cauchy)?

Any hint?

Comment: Use the fact that every Cauchy sequence is convergent and you are done.

Comment: Is that true?  I know every convergent sequence is Cauchy; the inverse is true?

Comment: In a complete metric space, every Cauchy sequence is convergent.

Comment: @NicholasStull So I should prove that this is a complete space.

Comment: Assuming $z\in\mathbb{C}$, it's a standard fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is complete with respect to the distance metric (and if you know how to prove that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is complete, modifying this proof for the case of $\mathbb{C}$ is elementary). It's even easier if $z\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The fact that every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ is convergent is a fundamental result of analysis, it would surprise me if it was not proven yet in your class/book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left | a_0 za_1 z^2a_2 ... \right |\quad< \left | a_0 \right | + \left | z \right | \left | a_1 \right | + \left | z^2 \right |\left | a_2 \right | + \dots$ 
since the sequence is bounded, there exists an upper
 
bound $(a)$ $\Rightarrow$ $LHS < \left | a \right |(1 + \left | z \right | + \left | z^2 \right |.....)\\ LHS < \left | a \right |(1/1-\left | z \right |)$
 which is a  finite quantity. Hence the  series converges.

[image]

you don't have to use Cauchy sequence

Comment: Instead of linking to a site that parses your latex to a gif take the latex code you have and add `$ ... $` around it and it will parse here. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference